# How to complete and fill in gaps between dates in SQL?

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I have data in Redshift that I'm aggregating to the Year-Quarter level i.e. number of items by Year-Quarter

I need to show a continuous trend and hence I need to fill-in the gaps in Year-Quarter. The picture below should give a clearer idea of my current data and desired output.

How can I achieve this in Redshift SQL?

[image]

Comment: Add a calendar tables will all entries and do a RIGHT OUTER JOIN with this table

Comment: @SQLpro I created a calendar table with all possible year-quarter entries and did 

RIGHT OUTER JOIN ON calendar.YearQuarter = originalData.YearQuarter.

It doesn't help as it ends up giving me the same number of rows as 'Original Data'

Comment: Because you do not do it properly. I suspect that you have add a restriction (WHERE or HAVING) on the first table, that you should place on the calendar table...

Comment: @SQLpro: Unless you can be more specific and tell me exactly what needs to be done, your answer doesn't help

Comment: SELECT ... FROM MyTable AS T RIGH OUTER JOIN Calendar AS C ON .... WHERE C.DAY_DATE BETWEEN T.begin_date AND T.end_date; the use only C.DAY_DATE in the SELECT part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A query like this should do the trick:

```
create table test (yq int, items int);
INSERT INTO test Values (20201,10),(20204, 15),(20213, 25),(20222, 30);

with recursive quarters(q) as (
  select min(yq) as q 
  from test
  union all
  select decode(right(q::text, 1), 4, q + 7, q + 1) as q 
  from quarters
  where q < (select max(yq) from test)
)
select q as yq, decode(items is null, true, 
    lag(items ignore nulls) over (order by q), items) as items
from test t
right join quarters q
on t.yq = q.q
order by q;
```

It uses a recursive CTE to generate the quarters range needed, right joins this with the source data, and then uses a LAG() window function to populate the items if the value is NULL.

Comment: All recursive solutions are the worst in terms of performances because they do iterate in a set based process. No index and no parallelism can be used when there is a recursive query...

Comment: While true in general, for generating small sets of data on the fly this is minuscule.  The alternative is to have a dist-all table around for use in the query which can be worth it for some larger use cases.   Are you thinking of another method / approach?

Answer (score 0):

This is known as forward filling values:

```
CREATE TABLE #Temp
(
    [YQ] nvarchar(5), 
    [items] int
)
INSERT INTO #Temp Values ('20201',10),('20204', 15),('20213', 25),('20222', 30)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
DECLARE @start int, @end int, @starty int, @endy int
SELECT @start=1, @end=4
SELECT @starty=MIN(Substring(YQ,0,5)), @endy=MIN(Substring(YQ,0,5)) from #Temp
;With cte1(y) as
(
    Select @starty as y
        union all
    Select y + 1
        from cte1
        where y <= @endy + 1 
)
, cte2(n) as
(
    Select @start as n
        union all
    Select n + 1
        from cte2
        where n < @end 
)
SELECT t1.YQ AS 'Year-Quarter', 
CASE WHEN t2.items is null then (SELECT TOP 1 MAX(items) from #Temp WHERE items is not null and YQ < t1.YQ) ELSE t2.items END AS '# Items'
FROM
(
    SELECT CAST(cte1.y AS nvarchar(4)) + CAST(cte2.n AS nvarchar(1)) AS YQ
    FROM cte1, cte2 
) t1
LEFT JOIN #Temp t2 ON t2.YQ = t1.YQ
WHERE t1.YQ <= (SELECT MAX(YQ) FROM #Temp)
ORDER BY t1.YQ, t2.items
```

Comment: I don't believe that this will work on Redshift.  The syntax is not correct in several areas.